# ASP.Net Simulating fade out effect from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit, effects

I have a code that set the text of a label to something from code behind and I want that label to disappear after some times? I've tried jQuery but don't want use timer to keep checking  if there is text then hide it :(. I heard about the Ajax Toolkit for ASP.Net but many reviews said that not all of the tools working properly now anymore. So anyone know a good solution for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you currently using ASP.NET Ajax to set the label, or is it being set when the page loads?
Why do you have to check it with a timer?

Comment: So when you set the text of the label, you then want it to fade out? So, is it for example a feedback label to inform the user that some action has taken place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you want to do is fade out the label shortly after you assign the text in code-behind...

You could wrap the label in an ASP.NET UpdatePanel.  Add an AnimationExtender from the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/UpdatePanelAnimation/UpdatePanelAnimation.aspx).  When you update the text in your code-behind, call the Update() method of the Update Panel and have that call a script OnUpdated.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="upnl" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Label id="lbl" runat="server" CssClass="fadeLabel"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender ID="upax" runat="server" BehaviorID="animation" TargetControlID="upnl">
    <Animations>
        <OnUpdated>  
            <Sequence>  
                <ScriptAction Script="fadeOut()" />
            </Sequence>  
        </OnUpdated>   
    </Animations>  
</asp:UpdatePanelAnimationExtender>
```

In your code behind:

```
lbl.Text = "Assign Text";
upnl.Update();
```

Then just have a method called fadeOut() within script tags in your page that performs the fade.

```
function BannerOut() {
    $(".fadeLabel").fadeOut(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that effect after a time, then a timer should run. You can use setTimeout method to do this

```
$(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       fadeText();
   },1000);

   function fadeText() {
       $("#yourlabelid").fadeOut("fast");
   }
});
```

This will fadeout your label after 1 second.